# How do I set a custom style to a BorderConatiner in Dojo using CSS

Tags: css, dojo, styling

I am trying to style a BorderContainer with CSS and it isn't working.  It works fine doing inline styles, but I want to use stylesheets.  I'm trying to use the baseClass to override any styling I can't get it to work.

```
<div baseClass="bodyContent" dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"></div>
```

CSS

```
.bodyContent {
border-right: 10px solid #B5BCC7 !important;
border-left: 10px solid #B5BCC7 !important; }
```

When I inspect the element on the page, it doesn't show the bodyContent styling.  Can you not use baseClass to override styles in layouts?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

baseClass is marked protected and is used by the widget internals to establish its own styles.  Have you tried just using 'class'?  That should be carried over to the new DOM the widget creates and usable by your CSS selectors.

Comment: I have tried that, reason it doesn't work is because the class gets overwritten.  When inspecting it, it shows class="bodyContentNoGutter dijitContainer bodyContent dijitLayoutContainer"

Comment: WFM: http://jsfiddle.net/7Anub/7/  What you show looks like it might be the result of using baseClass

Comment: You are right, looks like I had some bug in there preventing it from working...  All is working fine now, thanks!